# Books about industrial medical and culinary herb growing

Tags: agriculture

I planning to start my own medical/culinary growing farm somewhere in the not too far future. I'm on a training at the moment on this subject (I'll get a mid-level exam paper about it that I can use to work in this field). Luckily the literature in my native language (Hungarian) is pretty good but I would happily read something international on this subject to widen my views.

My question is that is there any literature on this subject? I'm interested in industrial growing only (like what machinery to use, how to grow herbs on hectares etc) but mainly what I get is how to grow a few herbs in your garden.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a question better suited for Gardening & Landscaping stack exchange.  That being said you could check out https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/ProducePlantProducts/UCM365142.pdf and https://www.nal.usda.gov/afsic/medicinal-and-culinary-herbs

Comment: @farrenthorpe You are probably right. I searched for farming & agriculture but saw that it was closed. Someone on the meta mentioned that people can use Earth Sciences and Biology as a replacement. Good to know that there is a stack exchange about gardening! :)